# Code blocks unreadable due to scrollbar

Tags: bug

On one-line code blocks, the scrollbar covers the content rendering it unreadable. See screenshot:

[image: Code block styling unreadable due to scroll bar overlapping the codeblock]

Comment: Yes that's my issue. Thanks for linking